# How would I find all records in a number column (Oracle) which have 3 digits in Sequence

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, loops, plsql

How would I find all records in a number column (Oracle) which have 3 digits in Sequence. Would I have to use substr to break down the number to individual digits and then subtract first and second digit to see if they are 1 or -1? Is there a better way to do it? Could I break down the number into digits and pass them to a varray in a pl/sql block? Please help.

[image]

Comment: What do YOU mean by "three digits in sequence"?

Comment: Do you consider `890` or `901` as "sequence"?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit 123 or 654 is considered a sequence. 890 or 901 is not. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you mean "sequential" as in 1-2-3, then you can use brute force:

```
(case when regexp_like(ssn, '012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789')
      then 'in sequence' else 'not in sequence'
 end)
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited this to include  sequential digits in descending as well                      case when regexp_like(ssn, '012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789|987|876|765|654|543|432|321|210')
      then 'in sequence' else 'not in sequence'
 end